# mysql exclude names from blocked table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to block certain lists, this is a command I have tried

`SELECT * FROM USER LIMIT 0, 50 WHERE`name`NOT IN (SELECT * FROM`exclude`)`

my exclude table contain user name i want block it but appears to be not working.

Comment: "appears to be not working" is not a description of the problem you're having. We have no idea what "be not working" means unless you explain it. Please be specific about the problem you're asking us to help you solve. We can't see your screen or read your mind from where we are, so we only have the information you give us in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recode it as a left join:-

```
SELECT `USER`.* 
FROM `USER`
LEFT OUTER JOIN exclude
ON `USER`.name = exclude.name
WHERE exclude.name IS NULL
LIMIT 0, 50
```

However if you wanted to do it using the same style as before you would need to return the matching field from the select from exclude, not every field (ie, not SELECT *)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `USER` 
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM exclude)
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: Note that some MySQL engine & locale combinations are case sensitive with respect to table and column names so it is more correct to use uppercase `USER` in "`USER`.name = exclude.name" in the above answer.  My edit to fix the accepted answer was not accepted by peer reviewer, so I am posting as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`SELECT * FROM USER LIMIT 0, 50 WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM exclude)`

The most likely reason for your query not working is that the `exclude` table probably has more than one column in it which would result in an error when you tried to run the query